# Acad 14 SOLIDS disappeared, DWG file doesn't open correctly

Tags: autocad

I made a drawing in Autocad 14 (Win XP) containing of mostly SOLID's. I saved and re-opened it multiple times without any problem. Before I last saved it I viewed my drawing using the SHADE functions.

After re-opening all my SOLIDS have disappeared. I spent numerous hours searching for a solution, tried SATFIX.ARX , AUDIT, RECOVER without success (ACIS error - which should be gone after applying SATFIX), changed my computer locale from German (decimal = comma) to English (decimal = dot) but my screen remains empty (and yes I tried to recover from a .BAK, too)

I also tried to export (the non-display drawing) into DXF and can confirm that all my objects are in there, but re-opening the DXF results in a huge ACIS error list again

I am desperate - please can someone help - thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone for reading .... I found a solution:

using the trial version of PlotVision7 (http://www.torro.de/plotvision/) I opened my corrupt DWG and saved it as a DXF which I was able to open and further edit in ACAD R14. The DXF still contained some errors which you usually get when you open ACAD files with earlier program versions than you used to create, but at least these errors are non-blocking and all drawing objects appeared again.